# SQL Compare 2 #temp tables and insert the differences into a 3rd #temp table

Tags: sql, t-sql, compare, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables A and B with the same structure. I need to get each row from table A that are not present in table B, then insert them into a 3rd #temp table C.

Each table has 2 columns that need to be compared, Type and Step, the remaining columns are RowID, CreatedDate, CreatedUserID, ModifiedDate and ModifiedUserID that do not need to be compared.

Is there a single statement I can use to INSERT INTO #tempC that compares A and B and will insert the values FROM A that are not present in TABLE B using TSQL (SQL SERVER 2012)

Comment: You should certainly be able to do that with a `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand that works great, I just changed the last FROM to #B not #C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL 2012 has the EXCEPT statement. Here's a trivial example.

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpA (
 Col Varchar(10),
 Irrelevant Int );

CREATE TABLE #TmpB (
 Col Varchar(10) );

CREATE TABLE #TmpC (
 Col Varchar(10) );

 INSERT INTO #TmpA 
 SELECT 'A', 0 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'B', 7 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C', 5 ;

 INSERT INTO #TmpB
 SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'D';

 INSERT INTO #TmpC
 SELECT Col FROM #TmpA 
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT Col FROM #TmpB

SELECT * FROM #TmpC;
DROP TABLE #TmpA, #TmpB, #TmpC;
```

--- And a second scenario following Blams critique

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpA (
 Col Varchar(10),
 Irrelevant Int );

CREATE TABLE #TmpB (
 Col Varchar(10) );

CREATE TABLE #TmpC (
 Col Varchar(10),
 Irrelevant Int );

 INSERT INTO #TmpA 
 SELECT 'A', 0 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'B', 7 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C', 5 ;

 INSERT INTO #TmpB
 SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'D';

 ;WITH Exceptions AS (
     SELECT Col FROM #TmpA 
     EXCEPT 
     SELECT Col FROM #TmpB
)
INSERT INTO #TmpC
SELECT A.Col, A.Irrelevant 
FROM #TmpA A
JOIN Exceptions E ON A.Col = E.Col

SELECT * FROM #TmpC;
DROP TABLE #TmpA, #TmpB, #TmpC;
```

Comment: That only inserts a single column.  He need 7 columns inserted and the exclude based on only 2 of the 7 columns.  SELECT Col, Irrelevant FROM #TmpA Except SELECT Col FROM #TmpB fails

Comment: @Blam Point taken: I have added a second scenario

Comment: I think my answer is a little more direct

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into #temp3 (Type, Step, RowID ..)
select #temp1.Type, #temp1.Step, #temp1.RowID 
  from #temp1  
  left outer join #temp2 
    on #temp1.Type = #temp2.Type 
   and #temp1.Step = #temp2.Step
 where #temp2.Type is null
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Aaron Bertrand, that is the simplest way, this is my statement:

```
INSERT INTO #C SELECT WFTypeID, WFStepID FROM #A EXCEPT SELECT WFTypeID, WFStepID FROM #B
```

Thanks for the other responses guys but that's too much code when you can do it in 1 line :)

Comment: So not clear that you did not want the other columns.  But if you did not want the other columns then that is the exact answer as posted by Tom Brown.

Comment: @Blam - Not clear? "Each table has 2 columns that need to be compared, Type and Step, the remaining columns are RowID, CreatedDate, CreatedUserID, ModifiedDate and ModifiedUserID that do not need to be compared." Tom Brown's answer is good but I did mention "Is there a single statement I can use to INSERT INTO" and Aaron's comment does exactly that, is simple and easy to read and understand.

Comment: Not clear that you do not want the other columns inserted.  See answer from Tom Brown INSERT INTO #TmpC SELECT Col FROM #TmpA  EXCEPT  SELECT Col FROM #TmpB.  How is your answer different?